# Side-by-side contact form and GMap using panels

Tags: 7, panels, google-maps, emails

I need a "contact us" page which has a contact form and google map side by side.
Thus, I enabled the core "Contact" module and installed [GMap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) module. I also installed 
[Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) module and [ctools](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) module to create a page with two columns layout.

I successfully added the contact form into the left column of the panel page, but I failed to add the map into the right column. I thought I can easily add a gmap block into the column, but I could not find any block provided by the GMap module.

How can I do that ? Can I create a block which displays the map by using [views](http://drupal.org/project/views).
I don't want to write custom codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way:

1. I enabled "GMap Macro Builder" which comes with the [GMap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) module.
2. Added a text format by enabling filter "GMap Macro expander" at the page "admin/config/content/formats/add" and named the text format as "Gmap Macro".
3. Created a map macro at the page "map/macro" to paste into a node.
4. Created a node at "node/add/page" by pasting the macro text copied from the step 3 into the node body, chose a text format "Gmap Macro" which was created from the step 2 and gave a title 'Location'.
5. Created a panel page with two columns layout and url "contact-us". Added the contact form to the left column.
6. Added the existing node "Location" created from the step 4 into the right column.
7. Created a main menu link with the path "contact-us" which is the panel page url.

Finally, I got a contact form with a google map side-by-side.

Required modules:
1. [Chaos Tool Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) ( Chaos tools and Page Manager enabled )
2. [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels) ( Panels only enabled )
3. [GMap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) ( GMap and GMap Macro Builder enabled )

Comment: Great option! You can add a map straight into a pane this way and select 'reusable' - very cool.